# Are there any halal restaurants in Mondulkiri?

Tags: food-and-drink, cambodia, islam

I cannot speak Khmer. I have never been to Sen Monorom before.

Can anyone let me know where to find halal food to eat?

Comment: Isn't this kinda broad seeing as Ratanakiri and Mondulkiri are both provinces. Or are you asking about Sen Monorom alone?

Comment: JoErNanO . now yes only Sen Monorom.  
i just back from Rattanak kiri and i found 2 of them.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you any specific recommendations, but both provinces do have small [Cham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cham_people) populations, who are Muslim keep halal.  So ask around for the local Cham community.

However, it'd generally [difficult to keep halal](http://www.phnompenhpost.com/post-weekend/halal-options-scarce-cambodia%E2%80%99s-devout-chams) even in Phnom Penh, much less in a place like Ratanakiri that's among the poorest in Cambodia.  [Cambodiahalatourism.com](http://cambodiahalaltourism.com) has a few listings, but it's pretty unclear if these actually serve halal food, or are just random sightseeing spots.

Comment: jpatokal: in capital city, there are Halal restaurant near the river.